# Невозможно крутить шестеренку точно в centre origin

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь создать эффект наведения, который будет вращать три разных иконки шестеренки svg вокруг их `centre origin`. Я пытался использовать `transform-origin` в качестве центра, но не не получилось.

*Ниже мой код:*

```css
.cog--middle {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

svg:hover .cog--middle {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<svg
  width="110px"
  height="100px"
  viewBox="0 0 110 100"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
  <title>ic--rollout</title>
  <g class="cog--middle">
    <path
      d="M33.6286316,13.9605932 C35.3737066,12.3664297 37.3249373,10.9942262 39.4376676,9.88864575 L37.7639337,2.84180199 L45.4931775,0.0900928417 L49.0720315,6.94284116 C50.0880101,6.82901642 51.1207261,6.7705605 52.1670931,6.7705605 C53.4317563,6.7705605 54.6764785,6.85595112 55.8958106,7.02128212 L58.4472618,0.245430567 L66.3935871,2.28698531 L65.5015991,10.2150059 C67.2900149,11.208746 68.956009,12.3961862 70.4712471,13.7489885 L78.472844,10.4564722 L82.3993634,17.661307 L76.7195784,21.8770189 C76.7662084,21.9692338 76.8123344,22.061747 76.8579526,22.1545548 C77.8852682,24.244573 78.6551102,26.4840416 79.1260955,28.831571 L86.6029963,29.8342633 L86.4016167,38.0374048 L79.2833198,38.8585809 C78.9039047,41.1188654 78.2488189,43.2856361 77.3538253,45.3231245 L82.6154298,51.0936912 L77.189124,57.2481974 L71.7016575,53.6264993 C71.4947362,53.835398 71.2844889,54.0409954 71.0710016,54.2432054 C69.5139432,55.7180126 67.7845278,57.0126257 65.9161266,58.0936683 L67.0389416,65.7326031 L59.0993207,67.8000862 L56.455254,61.4407304 C56.091817,61.4976526 55.7260194,61.5474549 55.3580085,61.5899901 C54.3111517,61.7109872 53.2463841,61.7731797 52.1670931,61.7731797 C51.0760163,61.7731797 49.9997819,61.7096216 48.9418893,61.5860052 L46.5757103,67.5520122 L38.6662197,65.3720638 L39.5343402,58.7054384 C39.3461507,58.6079107 39.1592312,58.5082724 38.9736132,58.4065544 C36.8360572,57.2351814 34.8710875,55.7880122 33.126567,54.1129174 L26.517699,57.3888051 L22.0982404,50.4754646 L27.2985471,46.0207673 C26.2463138,43.7967471 25.4835451,41.4089702 25.0588838,38.9060872 L17.8061497,37.9334569 L18.0075293,29.7303153 L25.1942049,28.9012511 C25.6358466,26.6699551 26.347362,24.5357377 27.2933125,22.5340431 C27.3591986,22.3946237 27.426222,22.2558471 27.4943708,22.1177255 L21.6159342,17.247506 L26.1330259,10.3975792 L33.6286316,13.9605932 Z M52.1670931,53.9156627 C63.0143367,53.9156627 71.807765,45.1208371 71.807765,34.2718701 C71.807765,23.422903 63.0143367,14.6280775 52.1670931,14.6280775 C41.3198495,14.6280775 32.5264212,23.422903 32.5264212,34.2718701 C32.5264212,45.1208371 41.3198495,53.9156627 52.1670931,53.9156627 Z"
      fill="#1B385C"
      id="wheel"
    />
  </g>
  <g class="cog--left">
    <path
      d="M9.03425644,68.7605395 C10.0306523,67.8355529 11.144758,67.0393549 12.3510762,66.3978604 L11.3954144,62.3090478 L15.8086266,60.7124149 L17.8520661,64.6886069 C18.4321654,64.622562 19.0218215,64.5886439 19.6192718,64.5886439 C20.3413641,64.5886439 21.0520705,64.6381904 21.7482798,64.7341209 L23.205097,60.802547 L27.7422576,61.9871248 L27.2329539,66.5872254 C28.2540962,67.1638264 29.2053388,67.8528186 30.0705033,68.6377594 L34.6392226,66.7273322 L36.8811707,70.9078164 L33.6381501,73.3539124 C33.6647747,73.4074185 33.6911115,73.4610977 33.7171585,73.5149479 C34.3037309,74.7276458 34.7432922,76.0270599 35.0122134,77.3891743 L39.2813439,77.9709696 L39.166361,82.7307046 L35.101985,83.2071781 C34.8853478,84.5186703 34.5113096,85.7759026 34.0002898,86.9581209 L37.0045394,90.3063952 L33.9062494,93.877444 L30.773038,91.7760145 C30.6548909,91.8972245 30.5348448,92.016519 30.4129487,92.1338479 C29.5239058,92.98958 28.5364512,93.7407575 27.4696391,94.3680142 L28.1107394,98.8003777 L23.577407,100 L22.0677085,96.3100908 C21.8601947,96.3431189 21.6513331,96.3720158 21.4412077,96.3966962 C20.8434777,96.4669027 20.235521,96.5029888 19.6192718,96.5029888 C18.9962932,96.5029888 18.3817893,96.4661103 17.7777581,96.394384 L16.4267268,99.8560592 L11.910598,98.5911809 L12.4062739,94.7229835 C12.2988222,94.6663948 12.1920957,94.6085813 12.0861123,94.5495611 C10.8656193,93.8698917 9.74366881,93.0301961 8.74758958,92.0582505 L4.97408501,93.9590292 L2.45068049,89.9476796 L5.41993035,87.3629165 C4.8191306,86.0724661 4.38360801,84.6869987 4.14113665,83.2347429 L-1.53588253e-12,82.6703906 L0.114982882,77.9106556 L4.21840174,77.429605 C4.47056851,76.134933 4.87682672,74.8965892 5.41694166,73.7351396 C5.45456105,73.6542439 5.49282981,73.5737211 5.5317411,73.4935783 L2.17529527,70.6677154 L4.75444596,66.6931605 L9.034257,68.7605397 Z M19.6192718,91.9437967 C25.8127869,91.9437967 30.8336229,86.8407471 30.8336229,80.5458164 C30.8336229,74.2508857 25.8127869,69.147836 19.6192718,69.147836 C13.4257568,69.147836 8.40492079,74.2508857 8.40492079,80.5458164 C8.40492079,86.8407471 13.4257568,91.9437967 19.6192718,91.9437967 Z"
      fill="#1B385C"
      id="wheel-copy"
    />
  </g>
  <g class="cog--right">
    <path
      d="M79.7529126,63.3257569 C80.7493084,62.4007703 81.8634142,61.6045723 83.0697323,60.9630778 L82.1140705,56.8742652 L86.5272828,55.2776323 L88.5707222,59.2538243 C89.1508216,59.1877794 89.7404776,59.1538613 90.337928,59.1538613 C91.0600202,59.1538613 91.7707267,59.2034078 92.4669359,59.2993383 L93.9237532,55.3677644 L98.4609137,56.5523422 L97.95161,61.1524428 C98.9727524,61.7290438 99.9239949,62.418036 100.789159,63.2029768 L105.357879,61.2925496 L107.599827,65.4730338 L104.356806,67.9191298 C104.383431,67.9726359 104.409768,68.0263151 104.435815,68.0801653 C105.022387,69.2928632 105.461948,70.5922773 105.73087,71.9543917 L110,72.536187 L109.885017,77.295922 L105.820641,77.7723956 C105.604004,79.0838877 105.229966,80.3411199 104.718946,81.5233383 L107.723196,84.8716126 L104.624905,88.4426614 L101.491694,86.3412319 C101.373547,86.4624419 101.253501,86.5817363 101.131605,86.6990653 C100.242562,87.5547973 99.2551074,88.3059749 98.1882952,88.9332316 L98.8293956,93.3655951 L94.2960631,94.5652174 L92.7863646,90.8753082 C92.5788508,90.9083363 92.3699893,90.9372332 92.1598639,90.9619135 C91.5621338,91.0321201 90.9541772,91.0682062 90.337928,91.0682062 C89.7149494,91.0682062 89.1004454,91.0313277 88.4964142,90.9596014 L87.145383,94.4212766 L82.6292541,93.1563982 L83.12493,89.2882008 C83.0174784,89.2316122 82.9107518,89.1737987 82.8047684,89.1147785 C81.5842754,88.4351091 80.4623249,87.5954134 79.4662457,86.6234679 L75.6927412,88.5242466 L73.1693366,84.512897 L76.1385865,81.9281339 C75.5377867,80.6376835 75.1022641,79.2522161 74.8597928,77.7999603 L70.7186561,77.235608 L70.833639,72.475873 L74.9370579,71.9948224 C75.1892246,70.7001504 75.5954829,69.4618066 76.1355978,68.300357 C76.1732172,68.2194613 76.2114859,68.1389385 76.2503972,68.0587957 L72.8939514,65.2329328 L75.4731021,61.2583779 L79.7529131,63.3257571 Z M90.337928,86.5090141 C96.531443,86.5090141 101.552279,81.4059645 101.552279,75.1110338 C101.552279,68.816103 96.531443,63.7130534 90.337928,63.7130534 C84.1444129,63.7130534 79.1235769,68.816103 79.1235769,75.1110338 C79.1235769,81.4059645 84.1444129,86.5090141 90.337928,86.5090141 Z"
      fill="#1B385C"
      id="wheel-copy-2"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54461709/7394871

Answer (score 7):

Шестеренки можно нарисовать в векторном редакторе, как видимо вы и сделали.

Но, при этом трудно найти точный центр вращения шестеренки.
При неточном указании центра вращения шестеренка будет вращаться с биением.

Я решил сначала выбрать центр вращения - `100,100px` и вокруг него создать шестеренку.

**Поэтапное создание шестеренки**

- Рисуем внешний контур шестеренки

При радиусе окружности `R=60px` длина окружности будет равна:

`C=2*Pi*R≈2*3.1415927*60 = 376.98`

- Узнаем длину сектора при наличии 24 зубьев шестеренки

`376,98 / 24 = 15,71`

Формула -  `stroke-dasharray="7.85 7.85"`

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
      <!-- big gear -->
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 7.85 7.85;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
</svg>
```

- Создаём спицы шестеренки

Рисуем линии с маркерами на концах

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
   
   <defs>
  <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker> 
   <!-- gear jumpers -->
  <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
     stroke:grey; stroke-width:6; ">
   
  </line> 
 </defs 

   <!-- big gear -->
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 7.85 7.85;  stroke-width: 10px;" /> 
    
    <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      
</svg>
```

- Клонируем перемычки и поворачиваем на разные углы

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
   
   <defs>
  <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker> 
   <!-- gear jumpers -->
  <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
     stroke:grey; stroke-width:6; ">
   
  </line> 
 </defs 

   <!-- big gear -->
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 7.85 7.85;  stroke-width: 10px;" /> 
        
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(240 100 100)"/>
</svg>
```

- Анимируем вращение шестеренки

```
<animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"
            dur="7s"
            repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
          />
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
   
   <defs>
  <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker> 
   <!-- gear jumpers -->
  <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
     stroke:grey; stroke-width:6; ">
   
  </line> 
 </defs 

     <!-- big gear -->
   <g>
       <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"
   dur="7s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
    />
  <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(240 100 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 7.85 7.85;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
    </g>

</svg>
```

- Точно также создаем маленькую шестеренку
- Добавляем кнопки управления вращения.

### Зубчатая передача готова

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
      <defs>
  <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker>  
      <!-- gear jumpers -->
  <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
     stroke:grey; stroke-width:6; ">
   
  </line> 
  <marker id="MarkerArrow2" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="3.5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="7" height="7" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker>
  <line id="line2" x1="168.5" y1="100" x2="211.5" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow2);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow2);
       stroke:grey; stroke-width:3.5; ">
   
  </line> 
  
     </defs>
      <!-- big gear -->
<g id="Big_Gear">  
  <g>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"
       begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="7s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
    />
  <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(240 100 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
    </g>
</g>
   <!-- small gear -->
<g id="Small_Gear" transform="rotate(20 100 100)">
  <g>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 190 100" to="-360 190 100"
       begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="7s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
    />
  <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(0 190 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(120 190 100)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(240 190 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="7.5"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 3px;" />
      <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="25"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 6px;" />
     <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="30"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 5px;" />
    </g>
</g>
<g transform = "translate(0,-165)">
  <g id="gO1">
   <rect x="35" y="165" height="20" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"/>
   <text x="50" y="181" font-size="18" fill="white">GO</text>
  </g>
 <g id="stop1">
 <rect x="100" y="165" height="20" width="60" rx="5" fill="red"/>
 <text x="105" y="181" font-size="18" fill="white">STOP</text>
 </g>
</g>  
 </svg>
```

### Три шестеренки

Их может быть и больше трёх, для этого надо клонировать шестеренки с помощью команды  -

`<use xlink:href="#Small_Gear" />`

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
      <defs>
  <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker>  
      <!-- gear jumpers -->
  <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
     stroke:grey; stroke-width:6; ">
   
  </line> 
  <marker id="MarkerArrow2" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="3.5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="7" height="7" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
  </marker>
  <line id="line2" x1="168.5" y1="100" x2="211.5" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow2);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow2);
       stroke:grey; stroke-width:3.5; ">
   
  </line> 
  
     </defs> 
<g id="two gears" transform="translate(25 0)">  
      <!-- big gear -->
<g id="Big_Gear">  
  <g>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"
       begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="7s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
    />
  <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(240 100 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: gray; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
    </g>
</g>
   <!-- small gear -->
  <g id="Small_Gear" transform="rotate(20 100 100)">
  <g>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 190 100" to="-360 190 100"
       begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="7s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
    />
  <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(0 190 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(120 190 100)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(240 190 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="7.5"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 3px;" />
      <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="25"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 6px;" />
     <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="30"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 5px;" />
    </g>
  </g> 
 </g> 
  <use xlink:href="#Small_Gear" x="-146" />
<g transform = "translate(-30,-160)">
  <g id="gO1">
   <rect x="35" y="165" height="20" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"/>
   <text x="50" y="181" font-size="18" fill="white">GO</text>
  </g>
 <g id="stop1">
 <rect x="100" y="165" height="20" width="60" rx="5" fill="red"/>
 <text x="105" y="181" font-size="18" fill="white">STOP</text>
 </g>
</g>  
 </svg>
```

### Пример планетарной передачи

```css
.parent{
position: relative;
}

.container{
width: 75%;
height: 75%;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0; 

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="container">
<svg  version="1.1"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' 
     viewBox="0 0 800 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">     >
  <title>animation planetary mechanism</title>
  <defs>
  <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
   markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
   markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
   <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="#22211D"/>
  </marker>
   <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
    style=" fill:none;
     marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
     marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
      stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:6; ">
   </line> 
    <marker id="MarkerArrow-s" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="1.7"
     markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
     markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
     <rect width="7" height="3.5" rx="2" fill="#22211D"/>
    </marker>
  <line id="line-s" x1="175" y1="100" x2="202" y2="100"
   style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow-s1);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow-s);
     stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:2; "  >
   
  </line> 
  <linearGradient id="vertical"
   
   x2="0%" y2="100%"
   spreadMethod="pad" >
     <stop offset="0%" stop-color="powderblue"/>
     <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightgreen"/>
  </linearGradient>
  
     </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#vertical)" />  
  <g transform = "translate(300,60)" >
   
    <g id="wheel">
     <g>
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"
       begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="14s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(240 100 100)"/>
    

     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
     <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="3"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
       </g>
    </g>

    <g id="col-small">
  
  <g>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       from="0 188 100" to="-360 188 100"
        begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="3.5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       />
     <use xlink:href="#line-s"  transform="rotate(0 188 100)"/>
     <use xlink:href="#line-s"  transform="rotate(120 188 100)"/>
     <use xlink:href="#line-s"  transform="rotate(240 188 100)"/>
     
     <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
     <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
     <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
     <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
 
  </g>
    </g>
 
    <g id="planetar" >
    <g>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       from="0 100 100" to="-360 100 100"
        begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="28s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
     />
    
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="116"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="124"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 12px;" />
     <circle cx="224" cy="100" r="3"  style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
  </g>
 </g>

  <g > 
   <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(240 100 100)"  />
   <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(120 100 100)"  />
  </g>

  <g transform = "translate(0,120)">
     <g id="gO1">
    <rect x="45" y="115" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue"/>
    <text x="62" y="132" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
     </g>
     <g id="stop1">
      <rect x="110" y="115" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red"/>
      <text x="120" y="132" font-size="16" fill="yellow" >STOP</text>
     </g>
  </g>
          
    </g> 
  </svg>
     
  </div>
   
 </div>
```

Источник ответа: @Alexandr_TT

Comment: Помнится, попадался. Спасибо, за подробное пояснение.

Comment: @L.F.C. так на enSO и попадался вам :)) Я там отвечал и оттуда сделана ассоциация

Answer (score 4):

Учитывая, что вы пытаетесь избежать использования `transform-box`, то одним из способов для достижения желаемого результата - поиграться со свойством `transform-origin`, используя процентные значения.

```css
.cog--middle {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 47% 34%;
}

svg:hover .cog--middle {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<svg width="110px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 110 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <title>ic--rollout</title>
      <g class="cog--middle">
        <path d="M33.6286316,13.9605932 C35.3737066,12.3664297 37.3249373,10.9942262 39.4376676,9.88864575 L37.7639337,2.84180199 L45.4931775,0.0900928417 L49.0720315,6.94284116 C50.0880101,6.82901642 51.1207261,6.7705605 52.1670931,6.7705605 C53.4317563,6.7705605 54.6764785,6.85595112 55.8958106,7.02128212 L58.4472618,0.245430567 L66.3935871,2.28698531 L65.5015991,10.2150059 C67.2900149,11.208746 68.956009,12.3961862 70.4712471,13.7489885 L78.472844,10.4564722 L82.3993634,17.661307 L76.7195784,21.8770189 C76.7662084,21.9692338 76.8123344,22.061747 76.8579526,22.1545548 C77.8852682,24.244573 78.6551102,26.4840416 79.1260955,28.831571 L86.6029963,29.8342633 L86.4016167,38.0374048 L79.2833198,38.8585809 C78.9039047,41.1188654 78.2488189,43.2856361 77.3538253,45.3231245 L82.6154298,51.0936912 L77.189124,57.2481974 L71.7016575,53.6264993 C71.4947362,53.835398 71.2844889,54.0409954 71.0710016,54.2432054 C69.5139432,55.7180126 67.7845278,57.0126257 65.9161266,58.0936683 L67.0389416,65.7326031 L59.0993207,67.8000862 L56.455254,61.4407304 C56.091817,61.4976526 55.7260194,61.5474549 55.3580085,61.5899901 C54.3111517,61.7109872 53.2463841,61.7731797 52.1670931,61.7731797 C51.0760163,61.7731797 49.9997819,61.7096216 48.9418893,61.5860052 L46.5757103,67.5520122 L38.6662197,65.3720638 L39.5343402,58.7054384 C39.3461507,58.6079107 39.1592312,58.5082724 38.9736132,58.4065544 C36.8360572,57.2351814 34.8710875,55.7880122 33.126567,54.1129174 L26.517699,57.3888051 L22.0982404,50.4754646 L27.2985471,46.0207673 C26.2463138,43.7967471 25.4835451,41.4089702 25.0588838,38.9060872 L17.8061497,37.9334569 L18.0075293,29.7303153 L25.1942049,28.9012511 C25.6358466,26.6699551 26.347362,24.5357377 27.2933125,22.5340431 C27.3591986,22.3946237 27.426222,22.2558471 27.4943708,22.1177255 L21.6159342,17.247506 L26.1330259,10.3975792 L33.6286316,13.9605932 Z M52.1670931,53.9156627 C63.0143367,53.9156627 71.807765,45.1208371 71.807765,34.2718701 C71.807765,23.422903 63.0143367,14.6280775 52.1670931,14.6280775 C41.3198495,14.6280775 32.5264212,23.422903 32.5264212,34.2718701 C32.5264212,45.1208371 41.3198495,53.9156627 52.1670931,53.9156627 Z" fill="#1B385C" id="wheel"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="cog--left">
        <path d="M9.03425644,68.7605395 C10.0306523,67.8355529 11.144758,67.0393549 12.3510762,66.3978604 L11.3954144,62.3090478 L15.8086266,60.7124149 L17.8520661,64.6886069 C18.4321654,64.622562 19.0218215,64.5886439 19.6192718,64.5886439 C20.3413641,64.5886439 21.0520705,64.6381904 21.7482798,64.7341209 L23.205097,60.802547 L27.7422576,61.9871248 L27.2329539,66.5872254 C28.2540962,67.1638264 29.2053388,67.8528186 30.0705033,68.6377594 L34.6392226,66.7273322 L36.8811707,70.9078164 L33.6381501,73.3539124 C33.6647747,73.4074185 33.6911115,73.4610977 33.7171585,73.5149479 C34.3037309,74.7276458 34.7432922,76.0270599 35.0122134,77.3891743 L39.2813439,77.9709696 L39.166361,82.7307046 L35.101985,83.2071781 C34.8853478,84.5186703 34.5113096,85.7759026 34.0002898,86.9581209 L37.0045394,90.3063952 L33.9062494,93.877444 L30.773038,91.7760145 C30.6548909,91.8972245 30.5348448,92.016519 30.4129487,92.1338479 C29.5239058,92.98958 28.5364512,93.7407575 27.4696391,94.3680142 L28.1107394,98.8003777 L23.577407,100 L22.0677085,96.3100908 C21.8601947,96.3431189 21.6513331,96.3720158 21.4412077,96.3966962 C20.8434777,96.4669027 20.235521,96.5029888 19.6192718,96.5029888 C18.9962932,96.5029888 18.3817893,96.4661103 17.7777581,96.394384 L16.4267268,99.8560592 L11.910598,98.5911809 L12.4062739,94.7229835 C12.2988222,94.6663948 12.1920957,94.6085813 12.0861123,94.5495611 C10.8656193,93.8698917 9.74366881,93.0301961 8.74758958,92.0582505 L4.97408501,93.9590292 L2.45068049,89.9476796 L5.41993035,87.3629165 C4.8191306,86.0724661 4.38360801,84.6869987 4.14113665,83.2347429 L-1.53588253e-12,82.6703906 L0.114982882,77.9106556 L4.21840174,77.429605 C4.47056851,76.134933 4.87682672,74.8965892 5.41694166,73.7351396 C5.45456105,73.6542439 5.49282981,73.5737211 5.5317411,73.4935783 L2.17529527,70.6677154 L4.75444596,66.6931605 L9.034257,68.7605397 Z M19.6192718,91.9437967 C25.8127869,91.9437967 30.8336229,86.8407471 30.8336229,80.5458164 C30.8336229,74.2508857 25.8127869,69.147836 19.6192718,69.147836 C13.4257568,69.147836 8.40492079,74.2508857 8.40492079,80.5458164 C8.40492079,86.8407471 13.4257568,91.9437967 19.6192718,91.9437967 Z" fill="#1B385C" id="wheel-copy"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="cog--right">
        <path d="M79.7529126,63.3257569 C80.7493084,62.4007703 81.8634142,61.6045723 83.0697323,60.9630778 L82.1140705,56.8742652 L86.5272828,55.2776323 L88.5707222,59.2538243 C89.1508216,59.1877794 89.7404776,59.1538613 90.337928,59.1538613 C91.0600202,59.1538613 91.7707267,59.2034078 92.4669359,59.2993383 L93.9237532,55.3677644 L98.4609137,56.5523422 L97.95161,61.1524428 C98.9727524,61.7290438 99.9239949,62.418036 100.789159,63.2029768 L105.357879,61.2925496 L107.599827,65.4730338 L104.356806,67.9191298 C104.383431,67.9726359 104.409768,68.0263151 104.435815,68.0801653 C105.022387,69.2928632 105.461948,70.5922773 105.73087,71.9543917 L110,72.536187 L109.885017,77.295922 L105.820641,77.7723956 C105.604004,79.0838877 105.229966,80.3411199 104.718946,81.5233383 L107.723196,84.8716126 L104.624905,88.4426614 L101.491694,86.3412319 C101.373547,86.4624419 101.253501,86.5817363 101.131605,86.6990653 C100.242562,87.5547973 99.2551074,88.3059749 98.1882952,88.9332316 L98.8293956,93.3655951 L94.2960631,94.5652174 L92.7863646,90.8753082 C92.5788508,90.9083363 92.3699893,90.9372332 92.1598639,90.9619135 C91.5621338,91.0321201 90.9541772,91.0682062 90.337928,91.0682062 C89.7149494,91.0682062 89.1004454,91.0313277 88.4964142,90.9596014 L87.145383,94.4212766 L82.6292541,93.1563982 L83.12493,89.2882008 C83.0174784,89.2316122 82.9107518,89.1737987 82.8047684,89.1147785 C81.5842754,88.4351091 80.4623249,87.5954134 79.4662457,86.6234679 L75.6927412,88.5242466 L73.1693366,84.512897 L76.1385865,81.9281339 C75.5377867,80.6376835 75.1022641,79.2522161 74.8597928,77.7999603 L70.7186561,77.235608 L70.833639,72.475873 L74.9370579,71.9948224 C75.1892246,70.7001504 75.5954829,69.4618066 76.1355978,68.300357 C76.1732172,68.2194613 76.2114859,68.1389385 76.2503972,68.0587957 L72.8939514,65.2329328 L75.4731021,61.2583779 L79.7529131,63.3257571 Z M90.337928,86.5090141 C96.531443,86.5090141 101.552279,81.4059645 101.552279,75.1110338 C101.552279,68.816103 96.531443,63.7130534 90.337928,63.7130534 C84.1444129,63.7130534 79.1235769,68.816103 79.1235769,75.1110338 C79.1235769,81.4059645 84.1444129,86.5090141 90.337928,86.5090141 Z" fill="#1B385C" id="wheel-copy-2"></path>
      </g>
  </svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54462033/7394871): @Yousaf